# How to submit a second form only after other form is successfully submitted

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular with UI Router and Firebase. There are two forms in two separate states on a single page: a contact form and a credit card form.

When the user clicks submit, the credit card info is submitted to Stripe. The contact form is then submitted to Firebase, but only after the credit card transaction has successfully completed. The following code works in development. But when the code is minified, the contact form is never submitted.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Controller for contact form:

```
.controller('ContactFormCtrl', ['$scope', 'Contacts', 'serviceB',  function ($scope, Contacts, serviceB) {
  var contactForm = this;
  var stripeDone = serviceB.get();
  contactForm.contact = {};
  contactForm.contacts = Contacts;

  $scope.$watch(serviceB.get, function(stripeDone) {
    if (stripeDone === 'yes') {
      console.log(contactForm.contact);
      Contacts.$add(contactForm.contact)
 } else {
      console.log('Card not charged');
       }
 }])
```

Controller for credit card form:

```
.controller('PaymentFormCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'serviceB', function ($scope, $http, serviceB) {

    $scope.handleStripe = function (status, response) {

    var stripeDone='yes';

        return $http.post(http://localhost:9000/api/payments, JSON.stringify(response))
       .then(function() {
         serviceB.set(stripeDone);console.log('serviceB set now',stripeDone);})
       .then(function() {$scope.payment={};
       })
       .then(function() {$state.go('thankyou');})
}]);
```

ServiceB service:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';
   angular.module('App')

  // ServiceB confirms that credit card info was submitted to Stripe
    .service('serviceB', serviceB);

    function serviceB () {

        var status = null;
        return {
           get: function () {
              return status;
      },
           set: function (value) {
              status = value;
    }
   };
   }
  })();
```

Contacts factory:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('contacts.fact', [])

  .factory('Contacts', ['$firebaseArray', '$q', 'FBURL', 'Auth', 'Ref', function ($firebaseArray, $q, FBURL, Auth, Ref) {

      var authData = Ref.getAuth();
      var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + '/contacts/' + authData.uid);
      return $firebaseArray(ref);
    }]);
})();
```

Router info:

```
.state('payment.details', {
      url: '/details',
      views: {

         'top': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/contact-form.html',
            controller: 'ContactFormCtrl as contactForm'

       },
         'bottom': {

            templateUrl: 'app/views/credit-card.html',
            controller: 'PaymentFormCtrl'
    // Note: not using controllerAs syntax because Angular Payments module does not support it
    },
     }
 })
```

**UPDATE**: If I move `.then(function() {$state.go('thankyou');})` from the controller for the credit card form, and place it at the end of `Contacts.$add(contactForm.contact)` in the controller for the contact form, everything works fine. This resolves the problem, but I'm skeptical that it's the correct solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like your $watch in ContactFormCtrl is having an issue. Does the console log print anything when minified? If not, something is going wrong with the serviceB.get bit.

Comment: @KumarM Thanks for the input. No, the `console.log()` in the contactFormCtrl doesn't print anything. I figured I'm doing something wrong with the $watch there, but can't figure out what.

Comment: `$scope.$watch(serviceB.get,` should probably be `$scope.$watch(serviceB.get(),` instead.

Comment: @Kato I modified the code as you suggested above, but still no luck.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work when minified, what exactly is the error?

Comment: IMO, the issue is because $state.go() is called before registered watch handler for serviceB.get is executed. This results in destroying the controller and the scope and never calling the watch handler in which you are submiting the second form because of the navigation to a different state.

Answer (score 3):

My suspect is that the watched expression: serviceB.get is messed up when the code is minified

```
$scope.$watch(serviceB.get
```

And also the idea of watching for change from service seems very awkward to me. Why don't you let credit controller to broadcast an event once it finishes processing and contact controller can listen to that event?

In credit controller, after receiving response from post request

```
function {
   serviceB.set(stripeDone);
   $rootScope.$broadcast("stripeDone");
   console.log('serviceB set now',stripeDone);
}
```

In contact controller:

```
$scope.$on("stripDone", function() {
    //process
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give your suggestion a shot. Any idea, though, why this watch works perfectly when served locally and not minified?

Comment: sorry, I'm not really sure on that either, my suspect is that the minification messed up the function name, but need to check your minified code to be sure

Answer (score 3):

It would actually be interesting to see your minimized code.

When not minified, the stripeDone parameter of the function hides, the local variable stripeDone. So you are evaluating the value of serviceB.get() in your if condition.

What might be happening is that when minifying, the minifier doesn't get that the parameter stripeDone is hiding the local variable and minifies the local variable stripeDone and the stripeDone in the if to the same identifier and the parameter stripeDone of the function to another parameter. So in the minimized case, what you really do is evaluating the local variable which value doesn't change (null) and not the new value (yes).

Why don't you just remove this line ?

```
var stripeDone = serviceB.get();
```

Just an hypothesis...